# RTMP URL in Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Mobile App for android and IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

can anyone he us for playing RTMP url in vs2017 Xamarin for android and IOS

we are currently using webview for the same

Comment: "can anyone help us" is not a good question.  Please read [ask]

Comment: For iOS, you could use LFLiveKit: https://github.com/rhedgpeth/Xamarin-LFLiveKit
For Android, you could use Yasea: https://github.com/rhedgpeth/Xamarin-Yasea